# Como mudar o nome da branch padrão que o Git cria?

Tags: git, github

Sempre que inicio um repositório local no Git, ele automaticamente cria uma branch `master`, porém no GitHub a branch padrão é `main`.

Ao invés de sempre ficar mudando o nome da local para `main`, tem como eu definir que o Git crie por padrão uma branch principal com o nome `main` também sempre que eu iniciar um novo repositório local?

Comment: o padrão é o `main` mas o github permite alterar , de acordo com o que menciona "  **Você pode alterar o nome padrão devido para fluxos de trabalho diferentes ou porque suas integrações ainda exigem “ master ” como o nome padrão da ramificação** " .. [github settings](https://github.com/settings/repositories)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode passar o nome do branch como parâmetro para `git init`:

```bash
git init --initial-branch=main

# ou
git init -b main
```

Ou, se quiser que sempre seja "main", adicione nas configurações:

```bash
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

Aí basta rodar somente `git init`, que ele criará o "main" por padrão.

---

Referência: [documentação oficial](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)